# HTML date picker overlaps date input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I use the following code, the date input fields are cut off and overlapped by the native HTML date picker:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <div class="input-group ml-2">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="date_from">von</label>
                </div>
                <input th:placeholder="#{date.format}" th:field="*{from}" type="date" max="9999-12-31" min="1000-01-01"
                       class="form-control" id="date_from">
            </div>
    <div class="input-group ml-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="date_to">bis</label>
        </div>
        <input th:placeholder="#{date.format}" th:field="*{to}" type="date" max="9999-12-31" min="1000-01-01"
               class="form-control" id="date_to">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like in the browser:
[image: von(from), bis (to)]

When hovering over the input, one can clearly see that it's the native HTML date picker that overlaps the input fields:

[image: overlaping input]

So my question is: How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use input type as text.

Comment: It would be heplful to see any custom CSS you are using on this page or if you are able to recreate this on a Fiddle or Codepen

Comment: @crazymatt I don't use any custom CSS. Only Bootstrap with Thymleaf as templating engine for Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of two options:

1. Specify the width of the input box to a value that allows the whole date to be clearly visible.`style="width:(insert value here)"`
2. Specify a smaller font-size, this will also allow the date to be seen clearly. `style="font-size:(insert value here)"`

Answer (score 2):

I deal with this everyday using the two steps Alex Morrison explained combined, also, don't forget that you can do both steps multiple times in different media queries to make it more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to manually add the width every time you have a date input, you could either create a custom class, or target each date in css and do something along the lines of `input[type=date]{width:(your width here);}`.